# Getting text from UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, text, uitextfield

I'm trying to see if what the user enters in a text field is equal to a string. For some reason, my app does not listen to:

```
[textField1.text isEqualToString:@"Blah"];
```

It also doesn't work with:

```
[textField1 text] isEqualToString:@"Blah";
```

It doesn't seem to respond to text. Yet, when I simply connect textField1 to a text view everything works beautifully! What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: if your textfield1 actually corresponds and is hooked up right..the first line of code should return TRUE if the text in it actually exactly equals @"Blah"

Comment: Do you get your expected string if you `NSLog(@"%@", textField1.text);`?

Comment: it the `textField1` set to nil?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
if ([textField1.text compare:@"Blah"] ==0) {
//its a match

}
```

Comment: unless the string has special characters, this shouldn't really do anything different than your first line of code.

Comment: if you're going to use `compare`, please use `NSOrderedSame` (instead of 0) for readability!

Comment: textField1 == nil, then this comparison "succeeds"

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest logging what you get from `textField1.text`. If the returned string is `nil` while there is text in the text field, then that means that your outlets haven't been connected properly. It's also important to realize that `-isEqualToString` looks for an exact match (case, whitespace, all of it) so even an extra space would cause it to return `NO`.

Comment: It returns NULL whether you type something in or not. I just want an exact match for now, and then I will do the stringRange thing later if needed. Thanks.

Comment: If it returns NULL even while there is text in the text field, that means that the outlets aren't connected properly. Double check your outlets and also make sure that you're calling `textField1.text` AFTER text has been entered.

Comment: Louie got it right. I replaced my code with his without touching the links and it works.

Comment: Louie's code will return `YES` when the text is `nil`. It isn't a proper comparison.